# How does a SE site in beta grab the attention of a dev when support tickets / bugs are reported that we can't answer?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange-2.0

[Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is in private beta. A user has [reported a support question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90/reputation-not-calculated-correctly) that I don't believe we as normal users can answer. What is the procedure for getting the attention of a dev or whoever the right person is to attend to it?

Also, now that I'm here: can someone attend to it?

Comment: attended it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devs check up on posts tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) periodically. I'm not sure if they do the same with [support](/questions/tagged/support), but you might want to add the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag. You can ping [Robert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) or [Rebecca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) in chat to be sure someone checks on it, but they should get to it either way

Comment: This was originally tagged bug, but as it turned out I doubted it was a bug so I retagged it support. I'll leave/add the bug tag in future then, when necessary.